# Interpretation of inverse ILR-transformed coefficients from a compositional data analysis

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, compositional-data

I wish to do regression analysis on compositional data. But whatever I've learnt from books and blogs that I need to use transformations like centered log ratio (`clr`), isometric log ratio (`ilr`) and then perform regression.

I found following example in *[Analyzing Compositions with R](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642368080)* by K. Gerald van den Boogaart.  (The dataset can also be found at [this link](http://www.stat.boogaart.de/compositionsRBook/).)

```
library(compositions)
# Strawberries = read.csv("Strawberries.csv")
Strawberries = read.table(text="C1          C2          C3          biomass
                                0.333333333 0.333333333 0.333333333 12.40632477
                                0.166666667 0.666666667 0.166666667 6.003719012
                                0.666666667 0.166666667 0.166666667 4.388704756
                                0.166666667 0.166666667 0.666666667 13.71033945
                                0.444444444 0.444444444 0.111111111 4.93935483
                                0.111111111 0.444444444 0.444444444 11.65310997
                                0.444444444 0.111111111 0.444444444 11.26699985",
                          header=TRUE)

X = acomp( Strawberries[,1:3] )
biomass = Strawberries$biomass
Y = log(biomass)
model = lm(Y~ilr(X))

# Output: 
lm(formula = Y ~ ilr(X))
Coefficients:
(Intercept)      ilr(X)1      ilr(X)2  
    2.12607      0.08851      0.53713
```

The author took the inverse of the ILR-transformed coefficients.

```
b = ilrInv(coef(model)[-1],orig=X)

# Output:
C1             C2        C3 
0.2387401  0.2705735  0.4906863
```

I tried using these coefficients over train data to check its authenticity. But predictions are too different. Can anybody explain how should I interpret these coefficients (`ilr` transformed and `ilr` inverse)?

Comment: How dou you check its authenticity?

Comment: I tried all these commands in r. Results are same.

Comment: If you are having trouble and are not getting the same answer, make sure you are using the correct basis for the ILR transform.